# Convert Complex Object instantiated via a yaml file to hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, object, hash, merge

How do I convert an object composed of other objects to hash? Take the following yaml file. A TestConfig object composed of a Limits object. When I load this file and try to convert, it doesn't convert the Limits object.

[image: yaml file]

Below is a code snippet, and the corresponding output. Is there something I'm missing or another way to do this? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish my goal? I want to de-serialize the yaml file, if the object attributes have changed, i.e. someone changed the class definition, I want to merge attributes and re-serialize the file. My thought was to convert both objects to hash, merge, then convert back to an object.

```
hash = {}
obj.instance_variables.each { |var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = obj.instance_variable_get(var) }
puts hash
```

{"color"=>"blue", "make"=>"Ford", "parts"=>["engine", "door", "hood", "tires", "etc"], "limits"=>#<Limits:0x00000000030e8ff0 @high=0, @low=0>}

Comment: You should just be able to read the file and strip the object notations prior to parsing the resulting yaml. E.g. `YAML.parse(file_str.gsub(/!ruby\/object.*\z/,""))`